# How to extract root domain name from multiple types of URLs, subdomains, URLs with port number, etc in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract just root domain name from the following subdomains, URLs in python.

```
1) https://abc.example.com/dir
2) http://abc.example.abde?param=value
3) https://aaa.abc.example.zaddj?param=value
4) tcp://cces.example.com:5598
5) ccc.ddd.example.com
```

I have treid multiples of methods as described following, but nothing works properly for all of these scenarios,

##### Method 1 tried: Using python library: urlparse

It is not working, as number 4 and 5 are non HTTP URLs and urlparse is not able to understand.
Used following code:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def get_root_domain_from_url(url):
    parsed_url = urlparse(url)
    domain_parts = parsed_url.netloc.split('.')
    if len(domain_parts) > 2:
        root_domain = domain_parts[-2] + '.' + domain_parts[-1]
    else:
        root_domain = parsed_url.netloc
    return root_domain
```

##### Method 2 tried: Using python library: tldextract

It is not working, as number 2 and 3 are non TLD domains so tldextract is not returning valid results.
Used following code:

```
import tldextract

def get_root_domain_from_url(url):
    extracted = tldextract.extract(url)
    if extracted.subdomain:
        root_domain = extracted.subdomain[:-1] + '.' + extracted.domain + '.' + extracted.suffix
    else:
        root_domain = extracted.domain + '.' + extracted.suffix
    return root_domain
```

##### Method 3 tried: Using python regex.

It is not working properly as URL scheme may changed for every scenario.
Also i am little weak in creating regex for such things..

I want result as following:

```
https://abc.example.com/dir -> example.com
http://abc.example.abde?param=value -> example.abde
https://aaa.abc.example.zaddj?param=value -> example.zaddj
tcp://cces.example.com:5598 -> example.com
ccc.ddd.example.com -> example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use *regex* approach with a [`search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search)/[`group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) this way:

```
def get_root_domain_from_url(url):
    p = r"(?:\w+://)?(?:\w+\.)*(\w+\.[a-z]+)(?:[/?:]?.*)"
    root_domain = re.search(p, url).group(1)
    return root_domain
```

- `(?:\w+://)?`     : *Matches an optional protocol specifier without capturing it*
- `(?:\w+\.)*`       : *Matches zero or
  more subdomains without capturing them*
- `(\w+\.[a-z]+)`  : *Matches the domain name (e.g., example.com) and captures it*
- `(?:[/?:]?.*)`    : *Matches an optional path after the domain without capturing it*

Test/Output :

```
for url in list_urls:
    print(f"{url} -> {get_root_domain_from_url(url)}")

https://abc.example.com/dir -> example.com
http://abc.example.abde?param=value -> example.abde
https://aaa.abc.example.zaddj?param=value -> example.zaddj
tcp://cces.example.com:5598 -> example.com
ccc.ddd.example.com -> example.com
```

> *Demo* : [[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zdiun7/1)]

Comment: Thanks, @timeless the code provided by you is working for me, and it's fulfilling my purpose.